# IF Statement For Number Range (standard_in) 1: syntax error

Tags: bash, unix, if-statement, bc

I'm trying to get an if statement to work with `bc` to determine if a number within a text file is within a numeric range or outside of it. I have conditions `(echoes)` that I would like to trigger when the criteria are (or aren't) met.

**climo.diff file:**

```
17.3
```

**Bash Code:**

```
check=`cat climo.diff`

if (( $(bc <<< "${check} < -7.0" || "${check} > 7.0") ));
then
echo "CAUTION: Outside acceptable range."
else
echo "Within acceptable range."
fi
```

I keep getting the **following error**:

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

Comment: Indeed the syntax is wrong. You are using the `||` operator inside an execution with `$()`. Basically you are trying to call the program `"${check} > 7.0"` which doesn’t make any sense. I’m no expert of `bc`, but I’d do something like `if bc <<< "${check} < -7.0" || bc <<< "${check} > 7.0"; then`. Maybe it can be done in one `bc` call instead of two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `||` needs to go inside the quotes so that it is considered part of the input to `bc`, rather than a shell operator separating the `bc` command from an invalid command name.

```
if (( $(bc <<< "${check} < -7.0 || ${check} > 7.0") ));
```

then

Comment: I continue to get the same error but, putting the `||` in side of the double quotes appears to have fixed the if statement and it appears to be working now for interrogating numbers.

Comment: What's the actual value of `check`? The error message is coming from `bc`.

Comment: The actual value of `${check}` is `17.3`. `bc` can handle floating point decimals so i don't believe that is the issue here.